# Jquery animate and offset causing unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, offset

I've been trying for hours to understand why the following occurs when I click the "menu trigger"

- The "menu trigger" works as intended (e.g. clicking the tree menu icon makes the menu go up and down) when the "content" is top 0
- When I scroll the "content" the "menu trigger" stops working

Can anybody help me understand why the "menu trigger" works fine when nothing is scrolled, but stops working as soon as I scroll the "content" box.

The top element is fixed and set to top 0, so it shouldn't be affected (to my understanding. Which obviously is lacking here haha. Still new to JS/Jquery).

[Here is a fiddle with everything I have now.](http://jsfiddle.net/kVk82/)

```
var topMenu = $('#topMenu');
var topMenuItem = $('#topMenu ul li a');
var top = $('#top');
var menuTrigger = $('.menu-trigger');
var time = 350;
var easing = 'easeOutCirc';

topMenu.css({
    'top': -(topMenu.outerHeight())
});

menuTrigger.on('click', function () {

    if (top.offset().top == 0) {

        top.animate({
            top: topMenu.outerHeight()
        },
        time,
        easing);

    } else {

        top.animate({
            top: 0
        },
        time,
        easing);
    };
});

topMenuItem.on('click', function () {

    if (topMenu.offset().top == 0) {

        top.animate({
            top: 0
        },
        time,
        easing);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the 'menu-trigger' button stops working when you scroll down the content is because of this line:

```
if (top.offset().top == 0) {
```

The #top div is set to 'position: fixed;' which means that when you scroll down the content the 'top' value of this div changes from 0 because it is no longer at the top of the document. This causes your if statement to no longer work as you intended.

Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kVk82/3/

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! Haha, such a small thing, yet I was thinking that the if statement might have something to do with it. But I didn't know how to have something other than the top offset trigger it. So I just learned the hasClass, addClass and removeClass trick  :)  Very nice!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Thanks, its a very useful technique :)

Comment: I've encountered another problem... When the number of options in the list go outside the screen, I can't scroll to them? I'm guessing this has to do with the fixed positioning, but how can this be counteracted? Any thoughts  :)

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle that shows this issue. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kVk82/7/ When you click the menu trigger, the menu goes "of screen", and it can't be scrolled  :(  What I'm looking to achive here is that when the menu is down, you should be able to scroll the content of the menu down to the menu trigger.

Comment: if you have an email/pm I can send you a link to the live dev site, so you can see the issue at hand live  ;)  Don't want to post links that will be dead for future thread visitors  :)

Comment: Here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kVk82/14/ - This is the way I would do it. The menu has a set height that shows 8 list items at any time and then a scroll bar to scroll through the rest of the list items. You could style the scroll bar to match your menu style. Is this what you were trying to achieve or do you want the menu to be full height? My email is ripzcurlz at gmail.com

Comment: Hey, first of thank you for your time man! :D  Second, correct, I need the menu to be full height, if you resize the "result" box in the fiddle so that the trigger goes beyond the bottom, you will see that the menu trigger can't be clicked anymore  ;)  So I'm trying to get the WHOLE menu (as is) to show, and be scrollable just to the point where the "top" ends. Would you prefer I email you?

Comment: Hey, no problem, happy to help :) Ah ok cool can you please email me the live dev site. Thanks